# Adding a custom status on a discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to add a custom status to my discord.js bot to request new developers, and it is not working. Here is my code:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Ready to comply.`);
 client.user.setPresence({
  status: 'online',
  game: {
   name:
    'need developers, DM Daniel for more info, BTW, you can learn the language at discord.js.org.', //The message shown
   type: 'PLAYING',
  },
 });
});
```

I have tried searching Stack Overflow, and found an answer that tells me to use the code above, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a custom status, which one of the recent Discord updates have introduced, it is not possible.

If you mean something like 'Playing with 100 commands' you can use:

```js
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use discord.js v12 then try this code, it works perfectly for me:

```js
client.user.setPresence({
 status: 'online',
 activity: {
  type: 'PLAYING',
  name: 'need developers, DM Daniel for more info',
 },
});
```